# What does "radical cube zero" mean?

Tags: infinity, radicals

My hobby is taking comics way too seriously. And I just came across a math topic. In a certain comic (Fantastic Four 51, according to some polls the greatest comic issue ever) there's a machine for entering other dimensions. Its inventor describes it as "a radical cube". So I Googled "radical cube" and I keep finding technical references to "radical cube zero" and "diminishing radical cube" in the context of mathematical dimensions. E.g. here: http://cds.cern.ch/record/1059354 I understand that "radical" in maths refers to roots, but what is "diminishing radical cube" or "radical cube zero"?

Thanks for any explanation. I asked the question on Reddit, and all they could do was point me here. :)

Comment: Found this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9905030.  So they seem to be talking about the Jacobson Radical.

Comment: For what it's worth, in mathematics, a "dimension" is not something that one can "enter". The dimension of a (vector) space is (roughly) the number of coordinates that it takes to fully specify a point in that space. So whatever references you've found to radical cubes (and I don't know what a radical cube is), it is doubtful that it has anything to do with entering or exiting other dimensions.

Comment: Based on the two links it looks like "radical cube" refers to things that are a product of three terms taken from the radical, which is a certain part of a certain mathematical object.

Comment: Thanks. That is slightly more understandable now. :) 

Re: entering dimensions - yes, I realise that a machine for entering another dimension is pure sci-fi :) But I still want to understand what the words mean.

Comment: There are several concept in mathematics called “dimension”, mostly having no connection whatsoever with “physical dimensions”. Comic strip authors are free of inventing whatever they like; personally I believe that the *flux capacitor* is better for time traveling.